# Multiple print unless perl

Tags: perl

I have a file that looks like this:

```
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding yes
#XAuthLocation /usr/X11R6/bin/xauth
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
```

I'm trying to write a script that uncomments the following lines:

```
#X11Forwarding yes
#XAuthLocation /usr/X11R6/bin/xauth
```

I have written following script:

```
open(my $in, '<', '/etc/ssh/sshd_config')
    or die "Cannot open /etc/ssh/sshd_config $!";

open(my $out, '>', '/etc/ssh/sshd_config2')
    or die "/etc/ssh/sshd_config2: $!";

while (<$in>) {
  print $out $_ unless /X11Forwarding/ ;
}

$txt='#X11Forwarding yes';
$txt=reverse $txt;
chop($txt);
$txt=reverse $txt;

`echo "$txt \n" >> '/etc/ssh/sshd_config2'`;
`mv '/etc/ssh/sshd_config2' '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'`;

close($in);
close($out);
```

Now this script works the way I want. The X11Forwarding segment is uncommented, but I can't seem to get it working so the XAuthLocation segment is also uncommented. Is there a way that I can print the file without the X11Forwarding and XAuthLocation segment?

Comment: `/X11Forwarding|XAuthLocation/` ?

Comment: Your down votes are likely due to the perceived "obviousness" of the answer or the sense readers have of a "lack of research effort". You can read [this **downvoting discussion** on Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) to get a sense of why things get downvoted.  Main take away: don't worry too much about it and live and learn ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have these two lines, and only want to uncomment them,

```
while (<$in>) {
  s/#\s*(?=X11Forwarding|XAuthLocation)//;
  print $out $_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here to make it official, just add the `XAuthLocation` Part to the *skip* line:

```
print $out $_ unless /X11Forwarding|XAuthLocation/;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single line:

```
perl -i -pe's/^#(?=X11Forwarding|XAuthLocation)//' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```